# Javascript add new row with <tr> then remove at the last row

Tags: javascript

I have simple question regarding table row.

Below is the example:

```js
var data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var element = `
    <td>${i}</td><tr>
  `;
  
  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result from console.log is:

```
<td>0</td><tr>
<td>1</td><tr>
<td>2</td><tr>
<td>3</td><tr>
<td>4</td><tr>
```

Now I need at the last row `<td>4</td><tr>` no need this `<tr>`. It should be like this `<td>4</td>`.

Is there any trick to handle it?

Comment: This HTML does not make sense. It is highly invalid. Can you please post the required end result?

Comment: Hi, before going to result, I need to make sure first on variable `element` last row is not added `tr`

Comment: Why are you adding a `<tr>` opening tag after a `</td>`, and never closing any of the opened rows? (The closing tag [is optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary), but the way you're constructing your HTML is confusing at best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  let element = `<td>${i}</td>`;
  if (i !== data.length-1) {
    element += "<tr>";
  }
  console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: Working good with this trick... cheers